# returning string to client from server with python

Tags: python, client-server

I am trying to make a very simple hangman game. I first show the client the number of spaces for the unknown word and then prompt the user to input a character to guess. I then send this character to the server side so then I can check the word to see if it contains the guessed letter. My problem is that I don't know how to make this updated version (like _ _ _ _ a _ _ _) a returnable value to send back to the client side. I know I shouldn't have the prints in but that was just to test if my check actually worked. But now I need to make it a value I can send to the client and I am not sure how to do this. This is currently the function I have:

```
def checkGuess(guessString):
for c in range(0, len(secretWord)):
    if secretWord[c] == guessString:
        print(secretWord[c], end="")
        #don't have to account for spaces in word with hard coded word
    else:
        print("_", end="")
return ???????

# now need to send the updated letters to client
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking, can you provide some example inputs and outputs?

Comment: @gommb   if the secretWord is like apple, and the client guesses the letter a. so guessString would be "a", I want that output to then be "a _ _ _ _" and then have that string sent back to the client so i can prompt the client for another guess and so on

Comment: What do you mean by sending it back to the client side?